# c++ shared_ptr does not provide a call operator

Tags: c++, constructor, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have a class `Foo` which contains a `shared_ptr` of class `Foo2` as a member variable. I am declaring the above sentece like this:

```
class Foo{
public:
    Foo();

private:
    shared_ptr<Foo2> f2;

};
```

First of all, can I do the above? i.e. not initialising the shared_ptr?

In the default constuctor of `Foo` I am initialising this shared_ptr varaibale like below:

```
Foo::Foo(){
    //create and calculate parameters a, b and c
    f2(new Foo2(a, b, c));
}
```

Since the only constructor of Foo2 has 3 arguments. This is however showing an error saying:

`Type 'shared_ptr<Foo2>' does not provide a call operator`

Isn't this the way to create a shared pointer instance of a class?

Comment: Simply use the initializer list of your constructor: `Foo::Foo() : f2(new Foo2(a, b, c)) {
}`

Comment: First of all, `f2` will be initialized using default constructor; second `f2(new Foo2(a, b, c));` is not a initialization at all, it is an attempt to call `operator ()` of `f2` object; third - perform actual initialization `Foo::Foo() : f2{::std::make_shared<Foo2>(a, b, c)} { }`

Comment: `Bar b(something;` and `b(something);` are very different things, even though they look superficially similar.

Comment: @VTT its declaring a smart pointer to the stack no?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I cannot do that since a, b and c are variables that are created in Foo() itself.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I know which is why I posted a question here since I would like a solution to the simple question.

Comment: @user7331538 You need assignment then. Post a [mcve] of your real code instead of providing us with bogus code please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `a`, `b` and `c` are only created in the constructor, you must re-assign `f2`. You cannot initialize a variable outside of its declaration or member initializer list (which is what you were trying to do).

Any of these will work:

```
f2.reset(new Foo2(a, b, c));
f2 = std::shared_ptr<Foo2>(new Foo2(a, b, c));
f2 = std::make_shared<Foo2>(a, b, c);
```

Answer (score 2):

> a, b and c are variables that are created in Foo() itself

Then use assignment operator:

```
Foo::Foo() {
    f2 = std::make_shared<Foo2>(a, b, c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want to do:

```
Foo::Foo() : f2(make_shared<Foo2>(a, b, c)) {
}
```

The error message you are seeing means that the syntax you were using tries to invoke `Foo::operator()(A,B,C)`, i.e. the call operator on the object. During initialisation however, the syntax calls the constructor instead.

If you insist on not initialising `f2`, you can also do this:

```
Foo::Foo() : f2(nullptr) {
   f2 = make_shared<Foo2>(a, b, c);
}
```

Note that the `: f2(nullptr)` part is not strictly necessary. I included it to show what is going on by default.

Comment: Apparently OP can't do that regarding their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57623752/c-shared-ptr-does-not-provide-a-call-operator#comment101701452_57623752).

Comment: Seems you have been outperformed by other answers. That's why I am not answering such incomplete questions trying to be the FGITW.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Fine by me, when I posted my answer, there were zero. But is my answer wrong?

Comment: I happen to think that your answer is the most correct. All the others are encouraging a redundant default construction.

Answer (score 0):

By doing f2(...); you are calling the [operator()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/operator_func/) method as `f2.operator()(...);`
What you need to do is initialize your pointer in the [initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

```
Foo::Foo()
: f2(new Foo2(a, b, c))
{}
```

Or create it in your constructor body using [std::make_shared](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) (this method hides the new operator)

```
Foo::Foo()
{
f2 = std::make_shared<Foo2>(a, b, c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is implemented incorrectly.

> ```
> Foo::Foo(){
> //create and calculate parameters a, b and c
> f2(new Foo2(a, b, c));
> }
> ```

The statement `f2(new Foo2(a, b, c))` does not initialise the member `f2`.   It attempts to use it as if it is a function (e.g. calling an `operator()` that accepts a `Foo2 *`).   The compilation error is because `std::shared_ptr<Foo2>` has no such operator.

A more correct implementation of your constructor would be to use an initialiser list

```
Foo::Foo(): f2(new Foo2(a, b, c))
{
}
```

This assumes `a`, `b`, and `c` are declared previously (in a manner visible to the compiler) and initialised.

If `a`, `b`, and `c` are initialised in the constructor body, then you need to do

```
Foo::Foo()
{
   //  define and initialise a,b,c
   f2 =  std::make_shared<Foo2>(a, b, c);
}
```

which is actually equivalent to

```
Foo::Foo() : f2()
{
   //  define and initialise a,b,c
   f2 =  std::make_shared<Foo2>(a, b, c);
}
```

In either of these forms, the default constructor of `f2` (which accepts no parameter) is called/invoked before the block of `Foo`s constructor is entered.   The statement `f2 =  std::make_shared<Foo2>(a, b, c)` constructs another object and performs a move assignment (which assumes `f2` is already constructed) not an initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives to initialize it in initializer_list when `a`, `b`, `c` need to be computed before:

- using lambda directly called (might also be free function)

  ```
  Foo::Foo() : f2([]()
      {
          //create and calculate parameters a, b and c
          return std::make_shared<Foo2>(a, b, c);
      }())
  {}
  ```
- delegating constructor

  ```
  Foo::Foo() : Foo(ComputeABC()) {}

  Foo::Foo(std::tuple<int, int, int> t) :
      f2(std::make_shared<Foo2>(std::get<0>(t),
                                std::get<1>(t),
                                std::get<2>(t)))
  {}
  ```